# jsonrpc4j mapping in spring doesn't work

Tags: spring, json-rpc

I'm trying to use the jsonrpc4j json-rpc library. Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected...
In fact my service doesn't get mapped at all. Here is some of my servlet-context.xml, I am using AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter (maybe this is the problem?):

```
<bean id="assistenzaJsonService"
        class="it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.assistenza.jsonrpcservices.AssistenzaJSonServiceImpl"></bean>

    <bean name="/AssistenzaServices.json" class="com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.spring.JsonServiceExporter">
        <property name="service" ref="assistenzaJsonService" />
        <property name="serviceInterface"
            value="it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.assistenza.jsonrpcservices.AssistenzaJSonService" />
    </bean>
```

the application is mapped at hostname.com/Appname and if I try hostname.com/Appname/AssistenzaServices.json i get 404.

Clues?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly hit `AssistenzaServices.json`. If you do so you will definitely get **404**.
You are missing **JSONrpc-spring** flow.

Instead of hitting `AssistenzaServices.json` in the browser you will hit `AssistenzaServices.html` or something like this as you configure things. After you hit it the java class and dojo `.js` file mapped to `AssistenzaServices.html` will get in action. Dojo `.js` file serviceHandler will use `AssistenzaServices.json` to map a class to fetch results to show on `AssistenzaServices.html`.

Answer (score 0):

The example on jsonrpc4j's homepage assumes that you use the "BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping".
I used the "SimpleUrlHandlerMapping" and it gave me a 404.

I solved it by adding this to the servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
```

And it worked with the following code( interface configuration as gotch4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojox.rpc.Service");
        dojo.require("dojox.rpc.JsonRPC");

        service = new dojox.rpc.Service({
            envelope : "JSON-RPC-1.0",
            transport : "POST",
            target : "http://localhost:8080/ajax/json/UserService.json",
            services : {
                helloSir : {
                    parameters : [ {
                        type : "string"
                    } ]
                }
            }
        });

        var response = service.helloSir("victorius");
        console.log(response);
    </script>
```